# Ubuntu 16.04 Unknown Additional Driver: Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs

Tags: 16.04, additional-drivers

I have this device is not working since I upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.
Should I enable it? and how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, without the microcode, Intel processors sometimes experience faulty behaviours.

In order to enable just tick the circle where it says **Using processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs...** , and click **Apply Changes** in the lower right.

Comment: Is there no problem while using this option?